# AWS NLB configuration for Tomcat hosts

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing

I have a network load balancer setup with a TCP listener on port 443, nd in my target group I have two UI EC2 instances, both running tomcat. I would like for the users to be directed to second UI node if the Tomcat service on the first UI node is down.
Both registered targets (First and second UI nodes) are healthy and the NLB is active.
To test, I put the NLB DNS name into my browser, it redirects to the first UI node. I stop Tomcat on that node and refresh my browser, but the connection does not get redirected to the second UI node. Could you please let me know what I am doing wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

A load balancer typically has a threshold for the number of requests it will attempt before it marks the target as unhealthy. Is this configured to an acceptable threshold? Also, when testing I would confirm that your system does not cache the page.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/network/target-group-health-checks.html

Comment: thank you for your reply. Here are the numbers I have, which ones do you recommend me to change and also, should I leave the stickiness on?
health checks:
TCP, traffic port, threshold: 3, unhealthy threshold: 3, Timeout: 10, interval: 30.
Target type is set to instance

Comment: Here are all the config values, which ones do you recommend me to change and to what value? Thanks

Protocol: TCP
Port: traffic port
Healthy Threshold: 2
Unhealthy Threshold: 2
Timeout: 10
Interval: 30